# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #280: Error

Tags: android, android-layout, memory, android-linearlayout, render

This is not a real question. I wanna share you the answers what helped me.
**Answers:**
This error is not always one performance error. This is one error what have 2 or more kind of answer.
**My first exp.:**
The Android Studio offer you to use TextView if you write two LinearLayout interconnecting. Because the second LinearLayout is can be replaced with TextView... And you replace to TextView 'cause you do not wanna see this many yellow error mark on your code. But this is not true. LinearLayout is not all the situations can be replaced with TextView. I show you why. **(I have a real exp. about this 'cause I had the same error.)**  Like that:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#d8000000"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:contentDescription="@string/describe"
                android:layout_width="128dp"
                android:layout_height="128dp"
                android:id="@+id/filter_1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:onClick="Click"
                android:clickable="false"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/string"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                />
            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Self-answered questions are ok, but please edit out the answer part and post it as an answer.

Comment: Thank's for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**So from the outside the second LinearLayout is can not be one TextView because AppCompatTextView can not be cast to ViewGroup.**(this is one render problem...)
And the second answer is:
**Maybe you have too many View in this layout, or too many image view with big pixel resolution and the android device is out of memory because this.**
**Good Luck With Errors Repairs**
&& I have one request.. if this methods do not work for you but you have one better share with the other people who have the same issue. Thank's.